# Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)

Tags: python-3.x, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-settings

I am creating an app in Django, and I am getting this error:

```
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)
```

I am using Elastic Beanstalk to host my website, and everything was fine until it started doing this.

My `settings.py` file:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'i1kf*^g1+dt*8n9bgcl80$d!970186x(x(9z2)7dfy1ynlxixn'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['travelApp-kool4-env.eba-pfvej56m.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com', "52.27.98.222", "35.166.8.118", "127.0.0.1",]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'sights.apps.SightsConfig',
    'itineraries.apps.ItinerariesConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'travelApp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
  '/home/django/myproject/templates',
)

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'travelApp.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'US/Central'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")]
```

I was previously trying to connect my app to PostgreSql, but I removed it because it wasn't working. That probably has something to do with it.

Does anybody know what is happening?

Comment: Were you testing your app using non-secure urls (i.e. `http`) before you switched to Elastic Beanstalk? Try adding `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True` to your `settings.py`.

Comment: I added it, but I am still getting the same error when I do ```eb deploy```